# Create new ibdata* file for each database in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb, restore

Is it possible the create a unique ibdate file for each database made in InnoDB ?

Because if I have multiple database made in InnoDB it will all store it in the ibdata1, ibdata2, etc...

Which make it difficult to just restore 1 database and not all clients who have InnoDB. MyISAM create multiple .frm, MYD and MYI file for each table which make it easier to restore.

How can we make in sort that restore is more easy on InnoDB. Do I have to make a DUMP .sql file or there's other solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't separate InnoDB data by database, but you can separate it by table, and the tables are stored under the respective subdirectory just like MyISAM tables would be.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html

But regardless of whether you use a central tablespace file or file-per-table, you should not back up or restore InnoDB databases by moving files around on the filesystem.  Even when you're not running queries to write to InnoDB tables, there are background threads that are processing the ib_logfile, undo logs, insert buffers, and other things.  Your data is spread in multiple places at any given time, and if you try to move InnoDB files around, you *will* corrupt them.

Instead, use mysqldump to make logical dumps of InnoDB data safely while MySQL is running.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've thought. Thanks

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to move binary files around when mysql service is turned off - I find cold backups very usefull for taking snapshots. Using mysqldump and then importing could take several hours for large data sets. I rarery have so much time during development.

Comment: @Arius2038, have you ever tried to restore a single InnoDB table from one of those snapshots?

Comment: @BillKarwin No I didn't. Can maybe you do it with percona innobackupex? If I would want single table from it I can import whole data ( few seconds ) and export single table. It's of course useful to have text backup too. However I wouldn't discard cold backups completely as they are very useful in real life. I see you have tons of experience with sql, but when you say " if you try to move InnoDB files around, you will corrupt them" thats not the whole truth.

Comment: @Arius2038, you're right, it is possible in theory. But one has to understand how the ibdata1 tablespace contains the data dictionary and sometimes part of the data of your table. So you can't just move an .ibd file alone and expect it to work.